# AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 503 for Views

Tags: views, ajax

I was trying to transfer my developed website from WAMP to Host - if I go to VIEWS - any button click responds with Error code:

```
AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 503
```

Then - I did a fresh install - Drupal 7.30 + VIEWS + (Ctools) - If I go to VIEWS - ANY button responds with

```
AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 503
```

- I mean - if I try to Enable any default Views - ERROR;
- If I click 'Edit' - it gives Error , but proceeds to edit screen...
- In 'Edit' screen - any button click gives Error, and nothing happens....
- PHP 5.3
- Litespeed
- it's a Shared Hosting, but I am able to change some PHP settings and extensions - I was trying to put more Max-Execution time - to 180 and more memory limit to 1024 , but to no avail so far....

What else could it be?!

Comment: Check your server logs, there will be an error message in there

Comment: After some disputes with hosting support and escalating the ticket they finally resolved it somehow by Changing PHP version to 5.4! Now it seems to work, but on home WAMP my PHP vesrsion was 5.3.13 and it was working; on hosting it was I think 5.3.28 and not working....

Comment: it could be a setting or php library is turned off by default on the server for that version, but turned on in 5.4, where it is turned on by default in WAMP in the lower version